# Dissociation equilibria of ammonium bifluoride in water

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, aqueous-solution

Ammonium bifluoride or ammonium hydrogen fluoride is a salt of a weak base and a weak acid.

The weak acid is because the second equilibria of $\ce{HF}$ written as:

$$\ce{HF + F- <=> HF2-}$$

and it has constant of $\pu{3.963 M}$.

But does the bifluoride anion further dissociate?

$\ce{HF}$ in water has many species: $\ce{H+},$ $\ce{F-},$ $\ce{HF2-},$ $\ce{H2F2}$ and $\ce{(HF)_nF-}.$ The $\ce{NH4HF2}$ has a more acidic $\mathrm{pH}$ than a solution of $\ce{NH4F}$.

Comment: Perhaps rather associate than dissociate. In concentrated HF(aq) and HF(l) there is also H2F+.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write out all the possible equilibria just like you do in the case of a multiprotic acid like Phosphoric acid. You will also need to have a pKa for every equation. The bifluoride ion will obviously dissociate in water

Comment: HF2- -> HF+F- (K=3.963 M), HF -> H+ + F- (K=6.85 x 10-4 M)... Like this?